# Can not upload next project on a cpanel hosting, npm package problem

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, cpanel, prisma

i've trying to upload next project on a cpanel but in there is a error while installing npm packages

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVEnpm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency treenpm ERR!
ERR! Found: next@13.5.3npm ERR! node_modules/nextnpm ERR!   
next@"^13.4.15" from the root projectnpm ERR! npm ERR! 
Could not resolve dependency:npm ERR! peer next@"2 - 5" 
from next-router@1.3.6npm ERR! node_modules/next-routernpm ERR!   
next-router@"^1.3.6" 
from the root projectnpm ERR! npm ERR! 
Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retrynpm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-depsnpm ERR!
```

this error pops up when installing npm packages, i've tried everything updating all the npm packages to the latest versions and it still does not works,

cpanel version :

```
Architecture : x86_64
```

```
operation system : linux
```

```
Perl Version : 5.26.3
```

```
Kernel Version: 4.18.0-372.16.1.lve.el8.x86_64
```

ive tried this npm command too but it does not worked also

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

server.js code is next

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? "localhost" : "website.com"


const port = process.env.PORT || 4790
// process.env.PORT || 4789

// when using middleware hostname and port must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass true as the second argument to url.parse.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
 
      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

package json looks like this,

```
{
  "name": "mywebsite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://website.ge",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.16",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.1.1",
    "@semcore/ui": "^15.24.0",
    "@studio-freight/lenis": "^1.0.19",
    "@types/node": "20.4.9",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.13",
    "framer-motion": "^10.15.2",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "i18next": "^23.4.4",
    "next": "^13.4.15",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.5",
    "next-intl": "^3.0.0-beta.10",
    "next-navigation": "^1.0.6",
    "next-router": "^1.3.6",
    "npm": "^9.8.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "prisma": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.4",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.6",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "swiper": "^10.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "usehooks-ts": "^2.9.1",
    "zustand": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/react-date-range": "^1.4.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

schema.prisma :

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["debian-openssl-3.0.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the cpanel node version they are using

Comment: 18.16.1 and 16.20.1 ive tried both does not works on any

Answer (score 1):

try to update npm packages manually or  with npm update so all the packages will be updated to the latest version

Comment: i've tried it but it didnt works

Answer (score 1):

You can install by adding this flag at the of command

```
  npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# or use the --force flag
npm install --force
```

or set it globally

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

or  the last alternative

delete node modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
```

clean the cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

run the above install command

Comment: there is still a error on cpanel's npm installation

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVEnpm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency treenpm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: kolos-resort@0.1.0npm ERR! Found: next@13.5.3npm ERR! node_modules/nextnpm ERR!   next@"^13.4.15" from the root projectnpm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:npm ERR! peer next@"2 - 5" from next-router@1.3.6npm ERR! node_modules/next-routernpm ERR!   next-router@"^1.3.6" from the root projectnpm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retrynpm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-depsnpm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken